# Sitecore smart publish

Tags: sitecore

I have a problem with smart publish.

When I do a smart publish in master database, after I refresh content folder to show the items that are publish correctly, but in content I haven't any item, and I should copy manually the items, I drag the item to show it in the web.

What can I do to solve this mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have workflow enabled? Is any of the items or their ancestors not in a final workflow state?

Comment: `but in content I haven't any item` - what do you mean, in the web database? Any errors in the logs? Is the item publishable also?

Comment: You should check publishing restriction as well

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-build the indexes for master,core and web, it will take time, but after that everything should work fine :
go to control panel -> indexing manager -> select **sitecore_core_index**, **sitecore_master_index and sitecore_web_index**. and click on rebuild button, and then publish the site:

[image]